# A question about Banach lattice

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Let $v$ be a real-valued function defined on any Polish space
>   $\mathbb{X}$ such that $v \geq 1$. The Polish space is a separable and
>   completely metrizable space, which is commonly used to avoid
>   measurability concerns.
>
> Denote by $B_v(\mathbb{X})$ the space of real-valued functions $f$ on
>   $\mathbb{X}$ such that $f(x)/v(x)$ is bounded as $x$ ranges over
>   $\mathbb{X}$, and consider the weighted sup-norm on $B_v(\mathbb{X})$:
>   $$ \|f \|_v = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \frac{|f(x)|}{v(x)} < \infty.$$
>
> Evidently, endowed with the finite weighted sup-norm,
>   $B_v(\mathbb{X})$ is a Banach space.
>
> However, **I'm wondering that is $B_v(\mathbb{X})$ a Banach lattice? If so, how to prove this?**

*My attempt:*
I was thinking to transform this weighted sup-norm  $ \|f \|_v = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{X}} \frac{|f(x)|}{v(x)} = \| \frac{f}{v}\|_{\infty}$ to a common supremum norm. I know that when $v(x) \equiv 1$, the vector lattice $B_1(\mathbb{X})$ of all bounded real-valued functions on $\mathbb{X}$ is a Banach lattice, but I got stuck in a more general weight function $v: \mathbb{X} \to [1, \infty)$.

I also thought that if the weight function $v: \mathbb{X} \to [1, \infty)$ is continuous, then $B_v(\mathbb{X})$ and $B_1(\mathbb{X})$ are homeomorphic. As a result, $B_1(\mathbb{X})$ is a Banach lattice, so is $B_v(\mathbb{X})$. I'm not sure whether this brief proof is correct, it is just my rough idea.

Any suggestions or idea is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its straightforward   that $B_u(X)$ is a Riesz space under the pointwise order and  for  $f\in B_u(X)$ its modulus $|f|$ is given by $|f|(x)=|f(x)|$ for every $x\in X$. Now let $f, g\in B_u(X)$ such that $|f|\leq |g|$, that is $|f(x)|\leq |g(x)|$ for every $x$ in $X$. Since $u$ is positive, $\frac{|f(x)|}{u(x)} \leq \frac{|g(x)|}{u(x)}$ for every $x\in X,$ which implies that $\|f\|_u\leq \|g\|_u$.